# Unsetting last remaining element in array

Tags: ksh

I am implementing various data structures (eg a stack) using arrays in ksh93, and would like to avoid keeping track of indices and counters, to keep things simple. I do a **push** using `array+=(element)`, and a **pop** using `print ${array[-1]}`, followed by `unset array[-1]`.

This generally works, except after popping the last remaining element on the stack (`array[0]`): when I push an item after that, it gets assigned to index 1, rather than 0. For example, if I run the following script with `PS4='> ' ksh -x`:

```
    typeset -a foo
    foo+=(a b c)
    print -C foo
    unset foo[-1]
    foo+=(d)
    print -C foo
    unset foo[-1]; unset foo[-1]; unset foo[-1]
    print -C foo
    print ${#foo[@]}
    foo+=(e)
    print -C foo
```

I get the following output:

```
    > typeset -a foo
    > foo+=( a b c )
    > print -C foo
    (a b c)
    > unset 'foo[-1]'
    > foo+=( d )
    > print -C foo
    (a b d)
    > unset 'foo[-1]'
    > unset 'foo[-1]'
    > unset 'foo[-1]'
    > print -C foo

    > print 0
    0
    > foo+=( e )
    > print -C foo
    ([1]=e)
```

All is good, apart from the last append operation. Even though the array is verified to be empty, it behaves as if it had a single null element at index 0.

I can work around the problem, eg by not depending on the first item being at index 0, or by keeping track of indices and doing explicit `array[index]=element` assignments, but I still wonder if I could avoid it altogether. I also know I can do `set -A array -- "${array[@]}" element` (this works as expected), but that is not as elegant as a simple `+=` operation. I have searched the man page, the Bolsky & Korn book, and the Rosenblatt & Robbins book, as well as online, but have not been able to find this behaviour documented anywhere.

Does anybody know why this happens, and/or how to avoid it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but it's some additional debugging steps that might help.

I've always used `typeset -p` to get a canonical representation of a variable. If you try it after running your last `unset`, you'll see that `foo` claims to still contain a `0` index, but with no value assigned to it. (This is different from having the empty string assigned to it, which shows up as a `''`. However, this contradicts various other array introspection forms, as you saw when you asked for the count of the array.

Frankly, i think this may be a bug in ksh, and the only solution may be reporting it to the [ast-users mailgroup](http://lists.research.att.com/mailman/listinfo/ast-users).

```
> typeset -a foo
> foo+=(a b c)
> print -C foo
(a b c)
> unset foo[-1]
> foo+=(d)
> print -C foo
(a b d)
> unset foo[-1]; unset foo[-1]; unset foo[-1]
> print -C foo

> print ${#foo[@]}
0
> typeset -p foo
typeset -a foo=([0]=)
> print ${!foo[@]}

> set -u
> print ${foo[0]}
./ksh: foo[0]: parameter not set
>
```